# Opacity on the ul working, but the buttons have opacity which I don't want

Tags: html, css

I've written some HTML and CSS code. Here's my HTML code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale:1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
    <a href=""><img src="../_images/imgres.jpg" id="Sushi" width="50" height="50" alt="Sushi" title="Sushi"></a>
    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" title="Home" id="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="About" id="about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="Contact Us" id="contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my CSS code:

```
/*CSS Reset*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

img#sushi {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 6;
    left: 6;
}

nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: aqua;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    padding: .7em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

nav ul {
    background-color: aqua;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
    opacity: .5;
}

nav li a#home {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6;
    right: 10;
    opacity: 1;
}

nav li a#contactus {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6;
    right: 110;
    opacity: 1;
}

nav li a#about {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6;
    right: 250;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I've run into an issue. I set the opacity of the UL to .5, and the buttons to 1. Problem is, the buttons are still at .5. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the opacity of an element, this affects all its children, and it can't be overridden. Instead, try setting an opacity of the background of the `ul`:

```
nav ul{
    background: rbga(‎0, 255, 255, 0.5);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set `opacity` on a parent, the children will inherit it. I presume you're setting the `opacity` on the `ul` because you want the background color to be semi-transparent? If so, use `rgba(0,255,255,0.5)` for 50% opacity `aqua`, then no need to specify `opacity` on the children.

```css
/*CSS Reset*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

img#sushi {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 6;
    left: 6;
}

nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: aqua;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    padding: .7em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

nav ul {
    background-color: rgba(0,255,255,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4em;
}

nav li a#home {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6;
    right: 10;
}

nav li a#contactus {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6;
    right: 110;
}

nav li a#about {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6;
    right: 250;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale:1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
    <a href=""><img src="../_images/imgres.jpg" id="Sushi" width="50" height="50" alt="Sushi" title="Sushi"></a>
    <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" title="Home" id="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="About" id="about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="Contact Us" id="contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The children will inherit the opacity, so either set it on the background of the parent, or, after setting it on the parent, explicitly set it on the children back to normal. This will only work if you order your code such that the children are set following the parent

Answer (score 0):

```css
  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  .wrap {
   position: relative;
  }
  .img-wrap, .btn-wrap {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
  }
  .btn-wrap {
   width: 100%;
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  }
  .btn-item {
   width: 100px;
   list-style: none;
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
  }
  .btn-item:hover {
   background: #ccc;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="wrap">
  <div class="img-wrap">
   <img src="https://ss1.bdstatic.com/5eN1bjq8AAUYm2zgoY3K/r/www/cache/holiday/habo/res/doodle/15.png">
  </div>
  <ul class="btn-wrap">
   <li class="btn-item">a</li>
   <li class="btn-item">b</li>
   <li class="btn-item">c</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

use background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);